# Change Layout for IntellJ Git Merge/ Resolve conflicts to 1 page vertical view

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

When I merge java code in intellj it seperate things into 3 tab vertical window with a tab for local changes, result and develop. This uses up a huge amount of screen real estate and is impossible to see all the code at once. It would be much preferable to have a 1 screen vertical layout, with the options then choose which change to select, by clicking accept to code stacked on top of eachother.

This is much more readable and usable by user and doesnt require constant horizontal scrolling and window size adjusting, when I'm writing angular code in vscode it gives me a layout like this. is there a way to achieve a similar layout and functionality in intellj?

Comment: On a side note, if you're doing excessive horizontal scrolling, that's usually a sign of either a lack of abstraction or poorly-formatted code. 80 or 120 characters should be an ideal limit for the size of your lines in most projects I've worked on.

Comment: Even something like 90-100 characters will cause excessive scrolling on any normal sized screen with all the spacing and extra details and line numbers shown by intellj

Answer (score 0):

There are some requests to redesign merge dialog window, please feel free to vote:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66552/Merge-dialog-should-not-be-modal-as-well-as-side-diffs-invoked-from-it

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66552/Merge-dialog-should-not-be-modal-as-well-as-side-diffs-invoked-from-it